# Why chosen select an element automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

When I use `chosen` in a `select box` then it will automatically select an `option` form `option list`.

When I click on `x` icon then it will show `data-placebolder` text.

But I Want to show default `data-placebolder` text.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select A User Group" id="user_group" name="user_group">
     <option> </option>
     <option value="1">Administrator</option>
     <option value="2">Operator</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({allow_single_deselect: true});
```

Comment: Consider using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) instead, it based on chosen, but has more features and bug-fixing.

Comment: its not possible this time. because I developed my application in a admin theme from themeforest. they integrated chosen. So that I have to use it. If I go to use `select2` then I have to make a lot of change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you, use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) instead of Chosen. Replace the first `<option></option>` with the below:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

It shows the default placeholder. Also, setting the `data-placeholder="Select A User Group"` doesn't just work. Add these too:

```
data-placeholder="Select A User Group"
placeholder="Select A User Group"
```

And also, in the `options`, pass this:

```
$(element).select2({
    placeholder: "Select A User Group"
});
```

Or, dynamically:

```
$(element).select2({
    placeholder: $(this).attr("placeholder")
});
```

---

If you still insist using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), here you go:

```
$(element).chosen({
    placeholder_text_multiple: $(this).attr("placeholder"),
    placeholder_text_single: $(this).attr("placeholder")
});
```

But don't forget to change the first option this way:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Comment: Can you please give a solution in Chosen?